# Add-on doesn't show up in the Toolbar

Tags: add-on

I am new to Blender, I've been playing around with it for about 2 weeks now, first time with a 3D software. I've done some tutorials and there are some where I have to go to user preferences and choose an add-on, the first time I did this, it was with the sapling add-on, worked fine, however today when I went to play around with it again, I checked the box, but the add-on settings that usually showed up on the tool bar on the left side of the screen isn't there. for any add-ons. I was really hoping someone could shed some light on why this is?

Answer (score 4):

Enabled add-ons can be enabled permanently by saving the user settings.

Otherwise they are enabled only on the current session, but will not be loaded next time you open Blender.

[image]

Comment: thank you for answering, I did try that, but it does not show up in the left hand tool bar in the first place, all I get is a blank tab underneath the "tools" saying operator and nothing is in it. thanks again for answering, but I must ask you to share your knowledge again lol

Comment: I figured it out, when I first used the add-on, it appeared on the tool bar tab that was already open, I did some rummaging through all of them and found it, apologies, I am a newb.

Comment: @Beizabel You should post that as an answer.